# Reinitialize jQuery plugin after AJAX page update

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-tools

I have an image carousel in home page. To render it i use Jquerytools ( scrollable+navigator )

I trigger the jQuery initializer script in this way:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $("#today-news-carousel").scrollable({ vertical: true, mousewheel: true }).navigator({ navi: '#today-news-navigator' });

 });
```

The content of this carousel can be updated by AJAX call.
After this call i need to reinitialize this carousel.
Here the function that makes AJAX call:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.nav-highlight', function() {

      var requestDateArray = $(this).attr('data-thedate').split('-');
      var d = new Date();
      var requestedDate = new Date(requestDateArray[0], (requestDateArray[1]-1), requestDateArray[2]);
      var today = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());
      if (requestedDate > today) {
          return
      }else {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: templateDir+'/highlight-news-navigator.php',
          context: this,
          dataType: "html",
          data: { date: $(this).attr('data-thedate') },
          beforeSend: function(){ 
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $('.today-news').fadeOut('fast', function(){
              $(this).empty().html(data).fadeIn('fast');
            });
          },
          complete: function(){
            $("#today-news-carousel").scrollable({ vertical: true, mousewheel: true })
            .navigator({ navi: '#today-news-navigator' });   
          }
        });

      }

  });
```

in the "complete" callback function i try to reinitialize the plugin but i have the following error in console:

```
TypeError: $(...).scrollable(...).navigator is not a function
.navigator({ navi: '#today-news-navigator' });
```

I cannot understand why it works correctly when i load the page and when i reinitialize it seems it cannot find .navigator method...

Comment: Is there a reason for putting the reinitialisation code in `complete`, instead of in `success`?  It would be more suited in the `fadeIn()` callback.  No promises, but worth a try.

Comment: Thaaaaank you!!! i spent all my afternoon on this issue! putting it in fadeIn callback works fine! thank you again!

Comment: ...Or instead of in  `$.ajax({}).done` ?

Comment: can you post that as an answer so this won't show up as unanswered?

Answer (score 1):

Thank to the help of a Archer i found the solution.
The script to reinitialize the plugin had to be located in the fadeIn() callback.
Here the working code:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.nav-highlight', function() {

      var requestDateArray = $(this).attr('data-thedate').split('-');
      var d = new Date();
      var requestedDate = new Date(requestDateArray[0], (requestDateArray[1]-1), requestDateArray[2]);
      var today = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());
      if (requestedDate > today) {
          return
      }else {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: templateDir+'/highlight-news-navigator.php',
          context: this,
          dataType: "html",
          data: { date: $(this).attr('data-thedate') },
          beforeSend: function(){ 
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $('.today-news').fadeOut('fast', function(){
              $(this).empty().html(data).fadeIn('fast', function(){
                $("#today-news-carousel").scrollable({ vertical: true, mousewheel: true }).navigator({ navi: '#today-news-navigator' });   
              });
            });
          },
        });

      }

  });
```

Comment: This SO discussion led me in the right direction--when detaching/reattaching elements with JQuery you have to reinitialize any plugins at the point of any animation completion.