# JQuery reel breaks inside AJAX called DOM change / insertion .load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-reel

It is a bit hard to explain everything I have done in this situation, but here I go...

From a nav / menu I am inserting a variety of PHP files with  content into my index page via `.on('click')` and `.load('page.php')...` one of those php pages includes 3 other php elements that are related to 2 JQuery reel instances and a 2 drop down selectors inside of another `.on('click')` that displays the instructions and the default images.

I have gotten all of my JQuery / raw JS to work inside the called PHP div - those related to the JQuery reel by using getScript inside of the `.on('click')->.load('page.php')...`

But even using getScript - JQuery reel only initializes the first time. I tried using window reload (because after going back to the home page - the first instance works again) before loading the div with the called PHP (it refreshed to the home page and didn't load the div), I tried clearing the JQuery cache, etc...

Long story short.
JQuery reel populates the head when initializing the css/images... on the first instance but not after that inside of AJAX called content.

Comment: Oh and as far as manually entering it into the head - because of the drop down selectors those "2" grouped "instances" of reel are actually 25 individual instances.

Comment: that was suggested here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31591634

Comment: and there was this :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19185245
but even if there were an "end point" for reel - this doesn't directly apply

Comment: I've tried MutationObserver, but I don't think I applied it correctly.  I got an alert, but the scripts didn't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was built in to JQuery reel all along.  Petre Vostrel is top notch. 
FROM: [GitHub Reel - issues](https://github.com/pisi/Reel/issues/279?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container)
"Hi, please use $.reel.scan() method after you inject the HTML. Excerpt from the documentation:

Responsible for discovery and subsequent conversion of data-configured Reel images is $.reel.scan() method, which is being called automagically when the DOM becomes ready. Under normal circumstances you don't need to scan by yourself.

It however comes in handy to re-scan when you happen to inject a data-configured Reel  into already ready DOM."